# How to create Vulkan Off-Line Rendering

Tags: rendering, vulkan

Where should I start on how to create offline animations with vulkan. I have never tried offline rendering before. What is it like, do we create very complex frames and store everything in a buffer then output a video out of it?

Comment: Offline Vulkan is almost identical to online Vulkan. You simply don't create a window or swapchain. So you're just rendering to images you create.

Comment: how do I store theses images and make a video out of it?

Comment: That's way too big of a question for SO. There are libraries you can use to take image data and compress it into a video.